# How to Change DBContext with ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In EF 4,when i Generating model from database, classes generating with DBContext and i have problem with this.i want to generating them with ObjectContext.
This model using in ASP.NET MVC 3 project.
What should i do for changing this to ObjectContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Reverting Back to ObjectContext Code Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581.aspx), the first web search result on your title.